# How to set default Master Page dynamically

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have two master pages. When the user logs in it should set first master page as default master page. If other login it should set second master page.

Comment: In childs pages you have a property called "MasterPageFile", have you tried changing it?

Comment: Yes I dont want to set that property in each & every page.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the default master page to use in the web.config file, using the `masterPageFile` attribute of the [`pages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363.aspx) element:

```
<system.web>
  <pages masterPageFile="~/DefaultMaster.master" />
  <!-- more configuration goes here... -->
</system.web>
```

The page will use that master page unless it has a `MasterPageFile` specified.

Answer (score 1):

As @RoBYCoNTe pointed out in the comments, you can set the `MasterPageFile` property on your pages.

If each page inherits from a common BaseClass, you can set the `MasterPageFile` property in your BaseClass to avoid having to do it on each individual page.